# Navigation.PopAsync showing the old page for a moment

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am calling `Navigation.PopAsync` to call the previous page. But, on the `OnAppearing` method of the previous page, I am refreshing data of listview by setting itemssource. But when calling popasync I am able to see the previous page with old data for a moment. After a moment the page refreshes and shows the correct data. Is there any way to hide the old data being shown?

Comment: this question is difficult to understand what you are asking. Maybe an example may help

Answer (score 1):

You could add `bool DataLoaded` property which implements `OnPropertyChanged` to your view model. Then bind this property to yours page `Content.IsVisibleProperty`. When you start refreshing your data simply set DataLoaded to `false`, and after it finishes set it to `true`. You could also add an ActivityIndicator for a better user experience (http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ActivityIndicator)

See Data Binding chapter: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0):

I removed listview in OnDisappearing method. Now, It is working correctly. It does not show old data any more.